# Pop Up Window in Symfony 2 and Parent Window

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I need create a new Pop Up Window with size specified in Symfony 2 with a form

In php, i create this with PHP and Javascript. **I don´t know how automatic update the parent window** by completing the form of the emerging child window .

Parent Window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
self.name = "ventanaprincipal";
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

<a href="#" onclick="window.open('ventanahija.php','ventanauno','width=200,height=200,scrollbars=no'); return false;">Abrir Ventana Hija</a>
</body>
```

PopUp Window

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function recargarprincipal(){    
window.open('principal.php?salir=gracias','ventanaprincipal');
self.close();
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="recargarprincipal();return false;">Procesar</a>
</body>
```

Does anyone know how to do it in symfony 2?

Comment: I recommend the Bootstrap/CSS modal dialog instead of a new window. see http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal&stacked=h for an example

Comment: This is the best solution! A lot of thanks @Frankbeen